# What are the alternatives for notify-send?

Tags: application-development, notification, development, alternative

I use `notify-send` for desktop notifications and I get notifications with expected summary and body. However, `notify-send` has limitations and so I would like a few recommendations on alternatives for `notify-send`.

I would like these extra features :

1. Expiration time.
2. Size customizations(size of the bubble).
3. Location modifications(location of the bubble).
4. Bubble look(color,transparency,shading)**(if possible)**.

I know `python-notify` and hesitate to use that as I am not familiar Python. I would like a complete stand-alone program. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unity, or any other desktop that uses Ubuntu's notify-osd, you don't have the option to change the notification bubble's size, position, look or how long it is displayed.

Comment: Can `notify-osd` be replaced by any other daemon, if available, which can be customised?

Comment: Probably, as long as they use the same XDG API

Comment: I was asking for the replacement, not just the possibility.

Comment: @mhall119, I see, but is it possible to send notifications like how sound/brightness notifications do? I could’t find anything on the web.

Comment: @VedVals Yes, you can replace it, although it doesn't always look pretty. iirc, gnome-notification-daemon is one option.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [yad](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/yad.1.html), which is a fork of **Zenity**.

Installation:

```
sudo apt install yad
```

If not available on your version, first run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt update
```

Learn about [`yad`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/yad.1.html):

```
man yad
```

It is not an ideal solution, but yad is powerful and flexible, and it has a time-out option.

Comment: `yad` doesn't work the way I want. It gives windowed notifications. It is great but I want something like `notify-send`, not windowed. Also, the system crashed on trying to get a notification bubble.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at yad as suggested by Paddy Landau. It allowed me to display a notification without a window border, that did not steal focus, and that automatically closed after 1 second. I could not find a way to change the window background color, but I could change the text color and size using [Pango Text Attribute Markup Language](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html). The following script increases volume by 3% then displays the current volume level using yad:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 3%+
VOLUME=`awk -F"[][]" '/Front Left.*Playback/ { print $2 }' <(amixer -D pulse sget Master)`
yad --timeout 1 --skip-taskbar --center --no-buttons --text="Volume:" --width=200 --text-align=center --undecorated --text="<span color=\"#ffffff\" bgcolor=\"#000000\" font_size=\"large\" font_weight=\"heavy\">      Volume: $VOLUME      </span>"
```